# AngularJS page does not refresh from server

Tags: angularjs, http, go, gorilla

I have an AngularJS app. The server side is Go and uses Gorilla Web Toolkit mux and sessions packages. The Angular app has two forms on the main page, Sign In and Sign Up. The data is posted to Go using AngularJS `$http.post` as JSON and appropriate responses are sent back from the server as JSON. What I want to achieve is that two different pages should be served on the main page of the website depending on if the user is logged in or not. Currently, when I submit the details of the Sign In form and the server responds with an appropriate response, I reload the page, but AngularJS keeps showing the page with the forms and not the new page.

AngularJS Code

```
angular.module('app', [])

angular.module('app').controller('SignInController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {}

    $scope.signIn = function() {
        $http.post('/signIn', {
            email: $scope.formData.email,
            password: $scope.formData.password
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if(data.ok == true) {
                window.location.reload(true)
            }
        })
    }
}])
```

Relevant Go Code
Below, the SignInHandler gets called on a POST to "/signIn" and the IndexHandler gets called on a Get to "/".

```
type JsonResponse map[string]interface{}

func (jr JsonResponse) String() (output string) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(jr)
    if err != nil {
        output = ""
        return
    }
    output = string(b)
    return
}

func SignInHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "user-session")

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var user User
    err := decoder.Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, JsonResponse{"ok": false, "message": "Bad request"})
        return
    }

    if user.Email == "" || user.Password == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, JsonResponse{"ok": false, "message": "All fields are required"})
        return
    }

    userExists, u := user.Exists()
    if userExists == false {
        fmt.Fprint(w, JsonResponse{"ok": false, "message": "Email and/or password in invalid"})
        return
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(u.Password), []byte(user.Password))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, JsonResponse{"ok": false, "message": "Email and/or password in invalid"})
        return
    }

    session.Values["userId"] = u.Id.Hex()

    session.Save(r, w)

    fmt.Fprint(w, JsonResponse{"ok": true, "message": "Authentication Successful"})
}

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "promandi-user-session")

    if _, ok := session.Values["userId"]; ok {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./views/home.html")
    } else {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./views/index.html")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that whether the session cookie is sent back when the page is getting reloaded?

Comment: Have you had a look to see what's going on with fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started behaving properly after I added the "Cache-Control": "no-store" header in my IndexHandler.

```
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-store")
```